# Dúvida, expressão regular em java

Tags: java, regex

Tenho as seguintes expressões regulares. A primeira valida palavras e está certa. O problema é na segunda que é pra validar diretório, como por exemplo "`home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt`". Não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela valide tal caminho. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
public class validador {

    public boolean validarPalavra(String palavra) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9a-z]*");
       Matcher retorno = p.matcher(palavra);
       return retorno.matches();
    }

    public boolean validarCaminho(String caminho) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("//([a-zA-z0-9])+");
       Matcher retorno = p.matcher(caminho);
       return retorno.matches();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, que o `Pattern` é um objeto caro de ser criado. Porém, ele é imutável e reutilizável, e portanto o melhor é que cada um seja criado apenas uma vez cada.

Segundo, que você usou na segunda expressão `[a-zA-z0-9]`. O `a-z` são as minúsculas e o `0-9` são números. Mas o `A-z` está errado porque o `z` deveria ser maiúsculo. Mas, ainda assim a expressão regular deveria ser bem mais complicadinha. A expressão regular correta (uma das possíveis) seria:

```
^(?:(?:[A-Z]\:)?\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)(?:\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))*(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?|[A-Z]\:\/?$
```

Explicação da expressão regular:

- `^` - Início da string.
- `(?:(?:[A-Z]\:)?\/)?` - Aqui temos algumas coisas:

  - `(?: ... )` - Serve para agrupar sem fazer captura. Temos dois grupos disso.
  - `[A-Z]` - Uma letra maiúscula.
  - `\:` - O caractere `:` após a letra maiúscula.
  - `(?:[A-Z]\:)?` - A letra maiúscula seguida do `:` pode ou não aparecer (por causa do `?`).
  - `\/` - O caractere `/`, que pode estar depois da letra maiúscula seguida do `:` ou logo no começo da string.
  - O último `?` do `(?:(?:[A-Z]\\:)?\/)?`. Significa que o `/` ou a letra maiúscula seguida de `:/` pode ser omitida.

  Ou seja, essa parte serve para reconhecer o prefixo do caminho. Assim sendo, nos caminhos do tipo `C:/texto`, `/texto` e apenas `texto`, isso é responsável por reconhecer o que antecede o `texto`.
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)` - O nome de um diretório. Aqui também temos várias coisas:

  - `(?: ... )` - Dois agrupamentos sem captura.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - Uma palavra. Tem que ter pelo menos uma letra (por causa do `+`).
  - `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - Um espaço seguido de uma palavra. O `*` sinaliza que pode ocorrer zero ou mais vezes. Sempre que ocorrer um espaço, deverá haver uma palavra logo em seguida.

  Desta forma, um nome de diretório consiste de um conjunto de uma ou mais palavras separadas por espaço. Espaços múltiplos consecutivos não são permitidos. Espaços no final ou no começo do nome não são permitidos.
- `(?:\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))*` - Aqui temos quatro coisas:

  - `(?: ... )` - Agrupar sem fazer captura.
  - `\/` - O caractere `/`.
  - `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)` - O mesmo que já foi mostrado anteriormente. Trata-se de um nome de diretório ocorrendo logo após a `/`.
  - `*` - Repete todo o grupo quantas vezes for necessário (incluindo possivelmente zero vezes).

  Ou seja, esta parte reconhece todos os `\palavras` após o primeiro termo. Inclusive se não houver nenhum `\palavras` após a primeiro termo.
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` - Novamente quatro coisas:

  - `(?: ... )` - Outro grupo sem fazer captura.
  - `\.` - O caractere `.`.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - Uma palavra após o `.`. Tem que ter pelo menos uma letra. Observe que não são permitidos espaços aqui (esta parte é a extensão do arquivo).
  - `?` - O grupo pode aparecer ou não.

  Portanto, esta parte reconhece o `.extensão` no final, que é opcional.
- `|[A-Z]\:\/?` - Tudo o que há antes reconhece o caminho completo. Entretanto uma vez que na parte anterior a isso tudo, a primeira palavra é obrigatória, então caminhos tais como `C:` e `C:\` não seriam reconhecidos. Por isso, temos o `|` (que significa que isso é uma alternativa se o que tem antes falhar) seguido de uma letra maiúscula (`[A-Z]`), um `:` e um `/` opcional (`\/?`).
- `$` - Final da string.

Ainda é importante notar que no java o caractere `\` é usado em strings para sequências de escape (tais como `\n` para quebras-de-linha). Como não queremos usar sequências de escape e sim usar o próprio caractere `\`, então dentro da string temos que usar `\\` para representar `\`. Assim, para construirmos o `\/`, o `\.` e o `\:` da expressão regular, no código-fonte temos que usar `\\/`, `\\.` e `\\:`, tal como você pode ver no código abaixo:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Validador {

    private static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9a-z]*$");

    private static final Pattern p2 =
            Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:[A-Z]\\:)?\\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)+(?:\\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*))*(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?|[A-Z]\\:\\/?$");

    public static boolean validarPalavra(String palavra) {
        return p1.matcher(palavra).matches();
    }

    public static boolean validarCaminho(String caminho) {
        return p2.matcher(caminho).matches();
    }
}
```

Por fim, vale ressaltar que no seu primeiro validador, você está usando `[A-Z0-9a-z]*` ao invés de `[A-Z0-9a-z]+` (ou seja, com `*` ao invés de `+`). Isso significa que ele também vai aceitar uma string vazia. Se isso não for intencional, então é só trocar o `*` por `+`. Além disso, eu também acrescentei o `^` e o `$` nela para marcar o início e o fim da string.

Bem, eis aqui alguns testes:

```
public class Main {
    private static void testar(boolean resultado, String teste) {
        System.out.println(Validador.validarCaminho(teste) == resultado ? "Ok" : "ERRO");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testar(true, "C:/home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "C:/home/Paulo Neto/Net Beans Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "/home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "/home/Paulo Neto/Net Beans Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "home/Paulo Neto/Net Beans Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(true, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto");
        testar(true, "home/Paulo Neto/Net Beans Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto");
        testar(true, "home");
        testar(true, "/home");
        testar(true, "C:/home");
        testar(true, "home.txt");
        testar(true, "/home.txt");
        testar(true, "C:/home.txt");
        testar(true, "C:");
        testar(true, "C:/");
        testar(false, "a:");
        testar(false, "a:/");
        testar(false, " home");
        testar(false, "home ");
        testar(false, "home/");
        testar(false, "home.");
        testar(false, ".txt");
        testar(false, "C:home");
        testar(false, "C:home/texto");
        testar(false, "home//texto.txt");
        testar(false, "ho  me/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeans#Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeans  Projects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto..txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.x.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt.");
        testar(false, " E:/home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "E :/home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "E: /home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "E:/ home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "E:/home /PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home /PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, " home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/ PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto /NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto. txt");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.txt ");
        testar(false, "home/PauloNeto/NetBeansProjects/Expre/src/expre/texto.t xt");
        testar(false, "E: ");
        testar(false, "E :");
        testar(false, " E:");
        testar(false, "E:/ ");
        testar(false, "E: /");
        testar(false, "E :/");
        testar(false, " E:/");
        testar(false, "");
        testar(false, " ");
        testar(false, "/");
        testar(false, ".");
        testar(false, ":");
    }
}
```

Em todos os testes a saída foi "ok".

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/LZcVec)

Comment: Victor Stafusa, entendi o que quis dizer, fiz da minha forma e ainda ta retornando "false", copiei seu código e ainda está retornando false

Comment: @PauloNeto Adicionei testes e coloquei online no ideone. Está funcionando. Se ainda dá errado para você, com qual string você está tentando?

Comment: realmente testei da maneira que me mandou deu certo, mas no meu não vai, segue o código postado no ideone

http://ideone.com/ckjKCv

Comment: @PauloNeto Estranho. O que é que você está digitando que não vai?

Comment: @VictorStafuse digitei um exmplo desse que está no seu e retorna false

Comment: @PauloNeto Qual exemplo? Digitou sem aspas? Você usou `/` ou `\\`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31281/discussion-between-paulo-neto-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 2):

Faz isso:

```
public boolean validarCaminho(String caminho) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\/]+");
       Matcher retorno = p.matcher(caminho);
       return retorno.matches();
}
```